# Android InAppBilling v3 [RPC:S-7:AEC-0]

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm updating inAppBilling from v2 to v3. Everything works fine except the last step of finalizing a purchase. I already read a lot about how to fix this problem, but clearing cache, factory reset etcetera does not work and is no real solution because the problem has to be somewhere else...

Error displayed to user:

```
Error retrieving information from server:
[RPC:S-7:AEC-0]
```

Possible related error in Logcat:

```
...
D/Volley﹕ [1] Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/commitPurchase
...
D/Finsky﹕ [1] PurchaseFragment.handleError: Error: PurchaseError{type=2 subtype=0}
```

Does anybody know what the reason for this problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it wasn't code related.

I filled out this form (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing?extra.IssueType=selling), adding my logcat information.

Next day I got a mail where google told me they fixed this problem. And the problem was gone :-)